# fsck_hfs keeps crashing when trying to repair my Time Machine volume

Tags: time-machine, hard-drive, disk-utility, crash, fsck

I've got my Time Machine volume (direct attached, USB) corrupted by accidentally flicking the switch while it's running. Now neither Disk Utility nor `fsck_hfs` can repair the drive.

Investigating it further, apparently `fsck_hfs` keeps crashing mid-way of the repair process. Is there a way around this? An excerpt of the crash log is as follows:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c91bd46 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a141ec0 __abort + 193
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a10377d __chk_fail + 35
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a103886 __snprintf_chk + 150
4   fsck_hfs                        0x0000000109bfc186 0x109be4000 + 98694
5   fsck_hfs                        0x0000000109bfec74 0x109be4000 + 109684
6   fsck_hfs                        0x0000000109bf9f8a 0x109be4000 + 89994
7   fsck_hfs                        0x0000000109bf21e7 0x109be4000 + 57831
8   fsck_hfs                        0x0000000109bf133f 0x109be4000 + 54079
9   fsck_hfs                        0x0000000109c0b1bb 0x109be4000 + 160187
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff86c927e1 start + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say it, but I think that Time Machine filesystem is broken beyond repair. You could try DiskWarrior, but it might not work either.

The fastest solution is to delete the USB volume from your Time Machine settings, then erase it and start a fresh Time Machine on it.

Comment: Disk warrior also doesn't work. It says "out of memory", but Activity Monitor says I still have 2GB free RAM and I've quit everything else except Finder.